what is the meaning of index[",i,"] in a loop?
what is the meaning of this part of my code?
my code haven't any problem but i wanna know what is the meaning of this part of my code:) thank you!
orginalString = input("enter the word: ")
print("orginal string:", orginalString)
size = len(orginalString)
print("printing only even index chars")
for i in range(0, size, 2):
    print("index[", i,"]", orginalString[i])

i wanna know why we should put i like this there? and what does it mean?

How did you write your code if you don't know what it means?

The loop isn't relevant. You have a similar line on print("orginal string:", orginalString). Do you understand that one?

@OneCricketeer That's not similar, doesn't have anything like index[",i,"] inside the string.

Every comma in a print statement creates a separator in the line.
If you want cleaner formatting, use f-strings
print(f"index[{i}] {originalString[i]}")


It prints the index number between the index[ and ], followed by the character in the string.
It's the same as print("index[" + str(i) + "]" + orginalString[i]).
